# Allocating Virtual Ram in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, memory

I need to install one of the Ubuntu 64 bits with at least 32 GB Memory, unfortunately I don't physically have 32 GB RAM, so what I am intending to do is allocate some of my RAM (let's say 2-4 GB) and the rest from my SSD.

Now up to this point it might sound easy, I could just allocate 2-4 GB memory from virtual host and while installing the VM I could specify vRAM swap as 30 GB. However that is not the case. The virtual machine has to be installed on an HDD. So in my case I will be installing my Ubuntu to my harddisk and use my SSD for most part of the memory.

My OS is Windows 8.1, and I could allocate Virtual Ram, but that wouldn't work because VirtualBox max limit for memory allocation is 8 GB.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

With Virtualbox you have to allocate to the VM whatever memory you can afford from your host machine's physical memory (you say 2-4 GB - which sounds fine). Then you have to allocate swap space (disk) inside the VM using whatever virtual disk space you assign to it.

This swap space will ultimately be provided from your host's HDD (SSD) but if you create it as a dynamically allocated VDI then at least it will only get physically written to if the VM writes to it.